# about difference between SI and CI for four years at some rate of interest.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The difference between SI and CI for the fourth year is 7280 at 20% per annum. What is the principal sum amount.

Answer (score 1):

If $P$ is the principal, what the SI?

CI +Principal after $n$th year is $$p\left(1+\dfrac{20}{100}\right)^n$$

So, the CI after fourth year  $$=p\left(1+\dfrac{20}{100}\right)^4-p\left(1+\dfrac{20}{100}\right)^3$$